# JavaScript try-catch not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Java Script. In the below code I am trying to create an error intentionally to learn how try...catch works. But nothing is running.

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
try {
    adddlert("Hi User!");
}
catch(Error e) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.message;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am missing?

Comment: **Always** have the browser developer console open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax Error:

Change your `catch (Error e)` as `catch (e)`.

More Info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: I shiver ever time I see a reference to [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) (click link to see why I believe they should be avoided)

Comment: @freefaller A lot has changed, quoted from w3fools `W3Schools still has issues but they have at least worked on the primary concern developers had. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources, so when you're ready to level up, move on.` with something as basic as try/catch, W3schools is more than enough.

Comment: Heres a reference that we can all agree on is quite good though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: I agree with @somethinghere. MDN is the best reference material out there. Avoid W3Schools.

Answer (score 6):

```js
try {
    adddlert("Hi User!");
}
catch(e) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.message;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```